# Filter array in object with multiple condition

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter

I'm doing a search feature that user will input there option in filter object, then they will get the list they want.
So i have an array like this

```
let array = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "form_items": [
      {
        "value_text": "test",
        "header_id": 1,
        "value_number" 2000
      },
      {
        "value_text": "test 2",
        "header_id": 2,
        "value_number" null
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "form_items": [
      {
        "value_text": "test 3",
        "header_id": 3,
        "value_number": 1000
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

and i have an object for filter like this

```
let filter = {
    "value_text": "test 2",
    "value_number": 2000
}
```

how can i return my array base on my filter object that element in form_items array match the condition ex: "test 2" in "header_id" : 2 and 2000 in "header_id" : 1

So my result will looks like this

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "form_items": [
      {
        "value_text": "test",
        "header_id": 1,
        "value_number" 2000
      },
      {
        "value_text": "test 2",
        "header_id": 2,
        "value_number" null
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: So You want to match all elements from array with form items matching your criteria? What if there is third element in first Obj? Do you want to present whole object, or only matching form_items?

Comment: Yes, i only want to filter form_items in each object with my criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with few loops, but It could be put into smaller functions.

```
var results = [];

for(const element of array){
    // 1. Find all formItems that are matching your filter for each element
    let matchingFormItems = []; // create an result array of formItems matching your filter criteria
    for(const formItem of array['form_items']){  // iterate over all form_items
       for(let filterKey: Object.keys(filter)){ // for each filter key, check if current formItem matches filter criteria
         if(filter[filterKey] === formItem[filterKey]){ // if filter key is matching property from the formItem, push it to result Array
            matchingFormItems.push(formItem);
            break;// if one filter is matching, you can skip other
         }
      }

    }

  // 2. If at least one formItem has been found - push new object to the result array
  if(matchingFormItems.length > 0 ){
     results.push({ // it's best not to mutate input array, so we need to clone the object with only desired formItems.
         'id': element.id,
         'form_items': matchingFormItems
     });
 }
}
```